# Spring CORS Support Custom Token Auth Solution

Tags: spring, cors, token

I'm trying to implement a custom token authentication solution.
The problem here is that i'm not able to run Cross Domain requests.
Tried a lot of different configurations but it all seems useless.

```
**Configure Http Security** 

  .csrf()
    .disable() //SCRF is disables
  .exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(this.unauthorizedHandler)
    .and()
  .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
  .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated();

// Custom JWT based authentication


httpSecurity
  .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Config of the implementation of Cors filter with custom Token.

```
**CorsFilter DoFilter **


HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); //Allow origin activated
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, " + tokenHeader);
if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

The code i've started from can be found here:
https://github.com/brahalla/Cerberus

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your filters are fine, you need to configure CORS - https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/#_enabling_cors. You don't seem to have any of that in your configuration